# java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.Arguments must be InterfaceMethodref constant

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, junit, junit5, junit-jupiter

```
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.Arguments
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.MethodSource

import java.util.stream.Stream

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat

@CompileStatic
class MyUnitTest {


    @ParameterizedTest(name = "{index} => myString={0}")
    @MethodSource("provideData")
    void test(String myString) {

        assertThat("hallo").isEqualTo(myString)
    }

    private static Stream<Arguments> provideData() {
        return Stream.of(
          Arguments.of("hallo"))
    }
}
```

Running this JUnit 5 test gives me the following error:
Method

> org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.Arguments.of([Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/junit/jupiter/params/provider/Arguments;
>   must be InterfaceMethodref constant
>   java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Method
>   org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.Arguments.of([Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/junit/jupiter/params/provider/Arguments;
>   must be InterfaceMethodref constant

I use Java 10 and I have JUnit 5 enabled in my build.gradle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your Groovy version seems to be too old.

Looks like you are bit by https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-7879
In case somebody uses Gradle, this error is also known there and reported via https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/721